# Azure ASP.NET Core - Error 500 for new files

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core application and use Azure as Cloud server.

Since yesterday all was working good, but I push to preproduction a new version of my application, and boom...

When I try to acceed to my new webapi controller , I have a Internal 500 error.
This is the log that I donwload from Kudu :

[image]

My controller is very basic, and the most strange is that older controller keep running

**EDIT**

The issue comes from a folder with an **cshtml** file that are not correclty publish to the azure website.

This file is use to create a email from an HTML Template, and when I use the Service that call this HTML template it throw an error.

I tried to add in my **csproj**

```
<None Include="$(ProjectDir)/EmailTemplates/OrderCompleteEmail.cshtml" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
```

but still not uploaded to azure... Any idea

Comment: Unfortunately, it says nothing. I suggest to use remote debugging and implement just a simple logger with Application Insights or Azure tables...

Comment: This happens to me many times as well. The issue will be eventually resolved by its own. I'd say this is Azure Platform issue itself.

Comment: I would turn on logging and check the log files: https://about-azure.com/2018/02/05/determine-whats-wrong-with-azure-web-app-deployment/

Comment: Could you check with Kudu and see that the web.config is there? You can go to `https://yourappname.scm.azurewebsites.net` and open the debug console there to check the files.

Comment: Configure the app to give you some more relevant information (the former `customErrors mode="Off"`). Things that might cause this are, among other things: wrong database or storage connection strings, missing (referenced) assemblies, miss-configured routes, etc

Comment: Database or storage are ok ( other database call works ). Assemblies that possible. Routes seems to be ok but can be the problem too. I'm currently can't check. I will back later with more information.

Comment: @MartinBrandl the logs helps me to find the issue. Many thanks

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the error you're getting is.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to turn on Logging:

- Go to the Kudu console (https://.scm.azurewebsites.net)
- select Debug console -> PowerShell
- Navigate to site -> wwwroot and open the web.config file
- Set the stdoutLogEnabled attribute to true and save the config.

Now,  you have to create a folder named "logs" in the wwwroot directory and restart your app.

Comment: Do you have any idea about my edit ? for the csproj ?

Comment: I had a similar issue with a xml documentation file created for swashbuckle - it was missing after I published the project. I remeber that I edited the csproj as well and had to configure something. I belive I found the answer here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/795

Comment: I will open an new issue. I tried different csproj from the github issue. Any are working... thanks

Comment: oh, sorry about that. Meanwhile I will try to find my csproj. Good luck.